# How can I repeat a property animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, viewpropertyanimator

I'm doing an animation of bubbles on the screen, but the bubbles stop after finishing the animation time. How do I repeat the animation or make it infinite?

```
bub.animate();
bub.animate().x(x2).y(y2);
bub.animate().setDuration(animationTime);       
bub.animate().setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        animators.add(animation); 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate looping animation with ViewPropertyAnimator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815784/how-to-generate-looping-animation-with-viewpropertyanimator)

Comment: You can also use `ValueAnimator` which supports repeats, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html

Answer (score 16):

Since `ViewPropertyAnimator` is only good for simple animations, use more advanced `ObjectAnimator` class - basically method [setRepeatCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setRepeatCount(int)) and additionally [setRepeatMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setRepeatMode(int)).

Comment: Yes, `ViewPropertyAnimator` is used for simple animations, for more complex usage, try `ObjectAnimator`. Sorry for unclear answer.

Comment: @asylume according to the dozen topics in here there is still no *good* way to repeat an `AnimatorSet` that consists of two `ObjectAnimator`s. If I missed smth, hit me up, please

Answer (score 9):

You can use `CycleInterpolator`. For example, like this:

```
    int durationMs = 60000;
    int cycleDurationMs = 1000;
    view.setAlpha(0f);
    view.animate().alpha(1f)
            .setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(durationMs / cycleDurationMs))
            .setDuration(durationMs)
            .start();
```

Comment: How would you make it infinitely animate ?

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example in Kotlin with a simple way to repeat the animation by recursively calling it in *withEndAction*

Example

```
private var animationCount = 0

private fun gyrate() {
    val scale = if (animationCount++ % 2 == 0) 0.92f else 1f
    animate().scaleX(scale).scaleY(scale).setDuration(725).withEndAction(::gyrate)
}
```

This repeatedly animates the size of a view to get smaller, return to normal, get smaller, return to normal, etc. This is a pretty simple pattern to repeat whatever animation you'd like.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. When you minimize the app this code will still work. So, animation needed to be paused (canceled) when the app is minimized and started again when app is open again

Answer (score 7):

This is actually possible. Here's an example of rotating a view:

```
        final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = view.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1000);

        animator.setListener(new android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            ...

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(final android.animation.Animator animation) {
                animation.setListener(null);
                view.setRotation(0);
                view.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1000).setListener(this).start();
            }

        });
```

You can also use "[**withEndAction**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withEndAction(java.lang.Runnable))" instead of a listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = view.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1000); //Animator object

    animator.setListener(new android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        ...

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final android.animation.Animator animation) {
            animation.setListener(this); //It listens for animation's ending and we are passing this to start onAniationEnd method when animation ends, So it works in loop
            view.setRotation(0);
            view.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1000).setListener(this).start();
        }

    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin you can do it like this. create a runnable. inside it animate the view and set `withEndAction` to runnable itself. and at the end run runnable to animation start.

```kotlin
var runnable: Runnable? = null
runnable = Runnable {
    view.animate()
        .setDuration(10000)
        .rotationBy(360F)
        .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
        .withEndAction(runnable)
        .start()
}
runnable.run()
```