# How to start multiple ObjectAnimator on view simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-animation

Here i am trying to move a view on a path with ObjectAnimator and also need to set one more scale animation on same view.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, View.Y, path);
        }
        if (objectAnimator != null) {
            objectAnimator.setDuration(2500);
            objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            objectAnimator.start();
view.startAnimation(scaleRection);// this is not working because changing of x y position
```

need to start another Animation when objectAnimator.start();

also tried with listener

```
objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    view.startAnimation(scaleRection);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator).

From the docs :

> This class enables automatic and optimized animation of select
>   properties on View objects. If only one or two properties on a View
>   object are being animated, then using an ObjectAnimator is fine; the
>   property setters called by ObjectAnimator are well equipped to do the
>   right thing to set the property and invalidate the view appropriately.
>   But if several properties are animated simultaneously, or if you just
>   want a more convenient syntax to animate a specific property, then
>   ViewPropertyAnimator might be more well-suited to the task.
>
> This class may provide better performance for several simultaneous
>   animations, because it will optimize invalidate calls to take place
>   only once for several properties instead of each animated property
>   independently causing its own invalidation. Also, the syntax of using
>   this class could be easier to use because the caller need only tell
>   the View object which property to animate, and the value to animate
>   either to or by, and this class handles the details of configuring the
>   underlying Animator class and starting it.

You can chain as many animations as you like at once in one line of code :

```
view.animate().translationX(...).translationY(...).scaleX(...).scaleY(...).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).setDuration(2500);
```

if you need different values for your duration or similar, you can do it with two lines :

```
view.animate().translationX().setDuration(...) ...    
view.animate().scaleX().setDuration(...) ...
```

There are also methods translationXBy() and scaleXBy() which might be more suitable for your case, and you can also set a listener etc. Check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) for all available methods

Comment: but i have path in which i want to animate.
than how to set path in your code ?

Comment: I dont think thats possible. You could keep your ObjectAnimator with path, and scale the view with ViewPropertyAnimator.

Comment: When using view.animate(), how to repeat animation infinitely ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345129/how-can-i-repeat-a-property-animation

Answer (score 4):

You can also use an `AnimatorSet` play together [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#playTogether](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#playTogether(java.util.Collection%3Candroid.animation.Animator%3E)) and it's builder function https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder

To play Two `ObjectAnimator` together

e.g.

```java
                AnimatorSet animationSet = new AnimatorSet();

                ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"scaleY", 1f, 0f);
                scaleY.setDuration(5000);
                scaleY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"scaleX", 1f, 0f);
                scaleX.setDuration(5000);
                scaleX.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                animationSet.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
                animationSet.start();
```